# Laravel - Getting error after postLogin validate

Tags: validation, laravel, laravel-5.1

Well, after validate, if my `password` is longer than 3 characters I get this error:

`Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::withInput() must be of the type array, object given, called in /home/vagrant/Code/stack-laravel/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/AuthController.php on line 50 and defined`

And this is my AuthController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    protected $redirectPath = '/admin';

    public $loginPath = '/admin';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'getLogout']);
    }

    public function getLogin()
    {
        if (Auth::user()){
            return redirect('/admin');
        }

        return view('admin.pages.login.index');

    }

    public function postLogin(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|min:3'
        ]);

        $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
            return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
        }

        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request)
            ->withErrors();
    }
}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$request` is an object, and `withInput()` takes an array of inputs to pass along.  In order to get an array of your request inputs you could do

```
return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->all())
        ->withErrors();
```

You can also call `withInput()` without any arguments and by default it will send all of the inputs along:

```
return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors();
```

In this particular case, you probably don't want to pass the password field input back (because they entered an incorrect password presumably, or for security purposes) so you could use the `$request->except()` method:

```
return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($request->except('password'))
        ->withErrors();
```

Edit: as for the second error, you actually don't need to use `withErrors()` when you use the `$this->validate()` method to validate the input.  See here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/validation#controller-validation .  With controller validation, they will automatically be redirected back by the `$this->validate()` function.  Instead, you could set your code up like this:

```
public function postLogin(Request $request)
{

    //Validate inputs

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:3'
    ]);

    if($validator->fails()){
        return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->all())
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    //Input is valid, now check credentials

    $credentials = $this->getCredentials($request);

    if (Auth::attempt($credentials, $request->has('remember'))) {
        return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
    }

    //Username and password are incorrect, redirect with error message

    return redirect($this->loginPath())
            ->withInput($request->all())
            ->with('error','Your username and password are not correct');

}
```

Lastly you will want to display the error message in your login view:

```
@if (session('error'))
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        {{ session('error') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

Comment: Works, but now error with `withErrors()`, this is happening: `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse::withErrors(), called in /home/vagrant/Code/stack-laravel/app/Http/Controllers/Admin/AuthController.php on line 51 and defined`

Comment: with your `postLogin()` if my password is larger than 3 characters and a real email is given a blank page is returned

Comment: OK i added a final redirect for when the username and password are wrong, and showed an example of how you could display that in your login page view

Comment: Cool, I'm starting to understand... You passed the error as session right? Can I pass it as variable?

Comment: `->with('error','Your username and password are not correct');` flashes a variable to the session called "error".  Within the view, you can then access this as `session('error')`.  You could use any name for this, eg `->with('foo','bar');` then in the view `{{ session('foo') }}` would print `bar` see: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/responses#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: Just for curiosity, I can't put it in the `$errors` variable? Something like this: `$errors->first('error')`?

Comment: Not that I know of, I think `$errors` just contains errors created by the validator.  I think flashing a variable to the session is the best option for this.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this:

```
return redirect($this->loginPath())
        ->withInput($validator)
        ->with('error','write here your error message');
```